# WordPress нужен подходящий плагин для календаря

Tags: wordpress, плагин, календарь, wordpress-плагины

Нужен подходящий плагин для реализации календаря со следующими требованиями:

1) Добавление ивентов с возможность краткого описания, указания даты, прикрепления картинки

2) Просмотр календаря в двух положениях, ивенты за месяц в форме списка по дням, ивенты за месяц в форме плитки (стандартный календарный вид) по дням

3) в форме списка просмотр краткого описания ивента с картинкой, датой и кратким описанием, кнопка для открытия расширеного описания, при нажатии на кнопку -  раскрытие дополнительного описания, показывается больше информации.

4) переход между месяцами должен осуществлятся по нажатию на кнопки "вперед"/"назад" (по принципу слайдера)
например: открыт месяц март, нажимаем кнопку "вперед" показывается Апрель, соответственно меняются ивенты и дни недели с датами

Comment: Поправьте заголовок.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все перечисленное есть в [Events Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/events-manager/). Вот [демо-сайт](http://demo.wp-events-plugin.com/).